Correctly position labels on Likert Graph using HH package in R?
I'm using the HH package in R to visualize likert data.  I've tried to create labels on the bars showing each percentage, but instead of getting the labels for each piece of the bar, I'm only getting one label per complete bar and it is not in the correct section.
How do I modify the custom myPanel function to get all four or five labels for each section?  And how do I ensure that they are located in the correct places on the bar?
I'm getting this.

But I want labels on the bars like this.  Or on all five sections of the bar instead.

library(HH)

myPanel <- function(x, y, subscripts, ...) {
    panel.likert(x, y, subscripts = subscripts, ...)
    cum_vals <- tapply(x[subscripts], INDEX = y[subscripts], FUN = cumsum)
    for (i in seq_along(cum_vals)) {
        panel.text(x = cum_vals[[i]] - x[subscripts][i] / 2,
                   y = as.numeric(y[subscripts][i]),
                   labels = paste0(round(x[subscripts][i], 1), "%"),
                   cex = 1, pos = 5)
    }
}

likert(type ~ . | Item, data = first_questions_data, layout = c(1, 10),
       scales = list(y = list(relation = "free")), between = list(y = .5),
       strip.left = FALSE, strip = strip.custom(bg = "gray97"),
       par.strip.text = list(cex = 1.1, lines = 1.2), ylab = NULL, cex = 1.2,
       ReferenceZero = 3, as.percent = TRUE, positive.order = TRUE,
       main = "As a result of the Dobbs decision I spend more time...",
       xlim = c(-100, -80, -60, -40, -20, 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100), 
       resize.height.tuning = 1, 
       rightAxis = FALSE, 
       col = c("#d8b365", "#ebd9b2", "#e5e5e5", "#acd9d5", "#5ab4ac"),
       panel = myPanel)

Data
structure(list(Item = c("educating myself on abortion legislation.", 
"educating myself on abortion legislation.", "educating other providers on abortion legislation.", 
"educating other providers on abortion legislation.", "discussing abortion legislation with my patients.", 
"discussing abortion legislation with my patients.", "worrying about my patients.", 
"worrying about my patients.", "coordinating abortion care for my patients.", 
"coordinating abortion care for my patients.", "I have felt torn between providing information about abortion and complying with legislation.", 
"I have felt torn between providing information about abortion and complying with legislation.", 
"I have felt an increase in time pressure due to gestational age limitations.", 
"I have felt an increase in time pressure due to gestational age limitations.", 
"My patients have been negatively impacted.", "My patients have been negatively impacted.", 
"My job-related stress has increased.", "My job-related stress has increased.", 
"My job satisfaction has decreased.", "My job satisfaction has decreased."
), type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("GCs in protective states", 
"GCs in restrictive states"), class = "factor"), `Strongly Disagree` = c(0, 
0, 0, 1.9, 7.1, 1.9, 35.7, 1.9, 71.4, 17.3, 71.4, 44.2, 42.9, 
9.6, 35.7, 1.9, 35.7, 9.6, 35.7, 17.3), `Somewhat Disagree` = c(28.6, 
1.9, 42.9, 15.4, 28.6, 1.9, 7.1, 7.7, 21.4, 13.5, 14.3, 15.4, 
14.3, 19.2, 7.1, 5.8, 28.6, 3.8, 28.6, 9.6), `Neither Agree nor Disagree` = c(0, 
15.4, 21.4, 11.5, 14.3, 9.6, 28.6, 3.8, 7.1, 19.2, 14.3, 17.3, 
14.3, 13.5, 21.4, 3.8, 21.4, 19.2, 28.6, 32.7), `Somewhat Agree` = c(57.1, 
25, 35.7, 30.8, 42.9, 28.8, 28.6, 26.9, 0, 9.6, 0, 9.6, 28.6, 
23.1, 21.4, 13.5, 14.3, 38.5, 7.1, 36.5), `Strongly Agree` = c(14.3, 
57.7, 0, 40.4, 7.1, 57.7, 0, 59.6, 0, 40.4, 0, 13.5, 0, 34.6, 
14.3, 75, 0, 28.8, 0, 3.8)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


I wasn't able to figure out what the library HH is doing with the likert::likert function...however, this makes it much simpler.
library(likert) 

# get data ready
tellMe = likert::likert(summary = first_questions_data[, c(1, 3:7)], 
                        grouping = first_questions_data$type)


# you know it's ready with %s because this function works:
summary(tellMe)

# before any of your customizations
plot(tellMe)

# with the customizations that didn't inherently present themselves

plot(tellMe) + ggtitle("As a result of the Dobbs decision I spend more time...") +
                        # note that this calls the --Y-- axis not X axis
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-100, -80, -60, -40, -20, 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100))


Just plot(tellMe)   ... none of your customizations that you used to create this appearance

With the title and x-axis breaks you specified

